# Compare SSI date against a javascript date

Tags: javascript, apache

I'm trying to write a form that will disable at a certain time and I want that to happen using javascript.  However, since people can easily change the date on their computer, I was hoping to use the date provided by Apache as the comparison date.  I tried some simple stuff but the SSI echoed date would not compare against the javascript date.  My code is below.  Any ideas?

```
var currenttime = '<!--#config timefmt="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->'
var currenttime = currenttime+' GMT-0400 (EDT)';

var disableDate = new Date();
disableDate.setFullYear(2011,9,18);
disableDate.setHours(17,0,0,0);

if(disableDate < currenttime)
    $('#date_field').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Please note that this is not the proper way to disable an element on a form.  I understand this, but I also enjoy learning JavaScript and I wanted to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a string to a date. Convert your `currenttime` string into a Date object first:

```
var currenttime = '<!--#config timefmt="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --> GMT-0400 (EDT)';
currenttime = new Date(currenttime);
```

That said, try instead to use [conditional SSI](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/conssi.shtml) to utterly disable the form server-side instead of getting JavaScript to do it for you.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks for helping me hack together this form.  I know there are better ways to do this but I partly just want to play with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't need that at all. If you rely on JavaScript to disable any logic, expect your page to be saved to a disk, JavaScript took apart, and form submitted any time now or two years later.

What you should focus on is "how can I deny *processing* this form at a certain time?"—and as you can see, the question does not depend on user clocks any more. Go server-side!

As of JavaScript, use it only for user's convenience. All the "security" rules are for server-side.

Comment: Alf, I realize people are going to mess with the javascript.  All form submissions are tagged in the database with the time they are received so I can still throw away entries that come in after the deadline.  I'm just looking for a quick/dirty way to disable part of the form after a certain time (a time when I'm not going to be in my office) so the majority of users will only be able to select the proper fields.  Also, I would go PHP and save myself a lot of problems but I included these forms in a CMS and changing them to PHP opens up a new can of worms.